# Angular not correctly compile ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I want directive which replace tag range=[-3, 3] to ng-options.

Unfortunately below solution is not good

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <title>Its directive range</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">      
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <select ng-model="value" range="[-3, 3]"></select>
            <span>{{value}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>      

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('directives', []);

        angular.module('app', ['directives']);

        angular.module('app').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.value = 2;
        });

        angular.module('directives').directive('range', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    range: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                    scope.options = [];

                    for(var i = scope.range[0]; i <= scope.range[1]; ++i) {
                        scope.options.push(i);
                    }

                    elem.attr('ng-options', 'o as o for o in options track by o');

                    elem.removeAttr('range');

                    $compile(elem)(scope);
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

After created ng-options tag select contain option value="number:2" instead of selected value 2 ...

Comment: I created plunker with your code, but cannot replicate mentioned issue, rendered HTML is:

Comment: plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/W0Uz9t4bnGh6feVqBYP4?p=preview

Comment: I set $scope.value = 2 in controller, but its not selected option ... and created option with value="number:2" ...

Comment: your directory creates an isolated scope, which blocks connection to $parent.value. One of solutions is just to pass ngModel as value via isolated scope: 
scope: {
    range: '=',
    value: '=ngModel'
},
see http://plnkr.co/edit/W0Uz9t4bnGh6feVqBYP4?p=preview

Comment: Its better - value 2 selected, but there is still left <option value="number:2"></option> in first case (with isolated scope) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ng-options* directive makes possible selecting different types of variables, it can select mixed types like:

```
<select name="mydata" 
        ng-model="number" 
        ng-options="value.a || value for value in ['-10', -5, 0, 5,'10',{a: '20'},'25']">
```

where first, fifth and last items are *STRINGs*, one item before the last is *OBJECT* and the rest of items are *NUMBERs*. In HTML these options are rendered like:

```
<select name="mydata" 
        ng-model="number" ng-options="value.a || value for value in ['-10', -5, 0, 5,'10',{a: '20'},'25']">
  <option label="-10" value="string:-10">-10</option>
  <option label="-5" value="number:-5">-5</option>
  <option label="0" value="number:0">0</option>
  <option label="5" value="number:5">5</option>
  <option label="10" value="string:10" selected="selected">10</option>      
  <option label="20" value="object:8">20</option>
  <option label="25" value="string:25">25</option>
</select>
```

to distinct between types, the type itself with semicolons is added before the value, like `number:5` or `object:4`, these type prefixes are ignored by *ng-model* which is updated properly, see plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/THIriUsSRMV3PPGvd8oN?p=preview.

I changed your range of numbers to range of strings, to make it similar to native HTML select element:

```
for (var i = scope.range[0]; i <= scope.range[1]; i++) {
  scope.options.push((i).toString());
}
```

type prefixes are omitted in this case, only on initial load there is `<option value="? string:2 ?"></option>` element, which is removed after first manual selection.

Comment: Before first manual selection there is option with value string:2. I try to find solve this problem. Perhaps exists method in Angular to symulate manual selection? :P

Comment: I have tried ngModelController.$render() and jQuery .val().trigger('change'), but did not succeed with it...